# Link shared library when it is in project workspace

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have simple application that should use shared library in Eclipse:.[image]

But when I build project I have message:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/gedas/workspace/doFis/libMyLib.so

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Add `libMyLib.so` to `l/home/gedas/workspace/doFis/`

Comment: But it is already there

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests the library name is wrong. It should try to link something like `-lMyLib` rather than the `-l<full path>`.

Typically the compiler invocation should look like this:
`g++ ... -L/home/gedas/workspace/doFis/ -lMyLib`
and then the linker will look for `libMyLib.so` in the library paths specified with `-L`.

I think you need to add a library path (from the `LibraryPaths` tab) to `/home/gedas/workspace/doFis/`  then add the library as `MyLib`.